# Loopback 4: Upload multipart/form-data via POST method

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I'm working in Loopback 4 and getting stuck in creating a POST method so that client can call this method and upload a multipart/form-data.
I read some examples:

- https://medium.com/@jackrobertscott/upload-files-to-aws-s3-in-loopback-29a3f01119f4
- https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-storage

But, look like they are not suitable for Loopback 4.

Could you help me to upload multipart/form-data via POST method in Loopback4.

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Support for `multipart/form-data` was added to LoopBack 4 recently via https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/pull/1936.

Because there are many different ways how to process the uploaded files, LoopBack 4 does not provide a generic file-upload solution out of the box. Instead, it allows applications to implement their own file-upload handler.

In the examples below, I am configuring `multer` to use memory storage. This is probably not what you want to do in production, please refer to [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) documentation to learn how to configure different storage backend.

Also note that you can use `multer` in TypeScript too, just install & add `@types/multer` to your `devDependencies`.

**1. Handle file upload inside your controller method**

You can tell LoopBack to skip body parsing and pass the full request to your controller method. In the controller method, call `multer` to handle file upload. A full working example can be found in [file-upload.acceptance.ts](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/packages/rest/test/acceptance/file-upload/file-upload.acceptance.ts), I am cross-posting the controller implementation here.

```js
class FileUploadController {
  @post('/show-body', {
    responses: {
      200: {
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {
              type: 'object',
            },
          },
        },
        description: '',
      },
    },
  })
  async showBody(
    @requestBody({
      description: 'multipart/form-data value.',
      required: true,
      content: {
        'multipart/form-data': {
          // Skip body parsing
          'x-parser': 'stream',
          schema: {type: 'object'},
        },
      },
    })
    request: Request,
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) response: Response,
  ): Promise<Object> {
    const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
    const upload = multer({storage});
    return new Promise<object>((resolve, reject) => {
      upload.any()(request, response, err => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve({
          files: request.files,
          fields: (request as any).fields,
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**2. Register custom LB4 BodyParser**

Alternatively, you can move parsing of file upload requests to a specialized body parser, and thus simplify your controller methods to receive the parsed result. This is especially useful when you have more than one controller method accepting file uploads.

A full working example can be found in [file-upload-with-parser.acceptance.ts](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/packages/rest/test/acceptance/file-upload/file-upload-with-parser.acceptance.ts), I am cross-posting the relevant snippets here.

The parser:

```js
class MultipartFormDataBodyParser implements BodyParser {
  name = FORM_DATA;

  supports(mediaType: string) {
    // The mediaType can be
    // `multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------979177593423179356726653`
    return mediaType.startsWith(FORM_DATA);
  }

  async parse(request: Request): Promise<RequestBody> {
    const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
    const upload = multer({storage});
    return new Promise<RequestBody>((resolve, reject) => {
      upload.any()(request, {} as any, err => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve({
          value: {
            files: request.files,
            fields: (request as any).fields,
          },
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Parser registration in your Application's constructor:

```js
app.bodyParser(MultipartFormDataBodyParser);
```

And finally the controller:

```js
class FileUploadController {
  @post('/show-body', {
    responses: {
      200: {
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {
              type: 'object',
            },
          },
        },
        description: '',
      },
    },
  })
  async showBody(
    @requestBody({
      description: 'multipart/form-data value.',
      required: true,
      content: {
        [FORM_DATA]: {
          schema: {type: 'object'},
        },
      },
    })
    body: unknown,
  ) {
    return body;
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct link to both the above snippets - https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/packages/rest/src/__tests__/acceptance/file-upload

Answer (score 1):

Loopback 4 team is implementing this feature: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/pull/1880

Hope the we will have it soon.

Comment: More info: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/the-journey-to-extensible-request-body-parsing/