# UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE error in loopback 4

Tags: javascript, loopback4

I am getting UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE error when I am trying to hit my API in loopback 4. Here is the complete error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 415,
        "name": "UnsupportedMediaTypeError",
        "message": "Content-type multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------940446802551357964885512 does not match [application/json].",
        "code": "UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE"
    }
}
```

I am sure where in the code do I add support for *multipart/form-data* since I am trying to process an uploaded binary file.

What can I do here?

Comment: This is the solution you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53726843/11933335

Comment: Yeah i have also done something similar to this. What loopback added was an option to bypass the request body parsing. And then you can pass it to a package like multer and get the files and other params.

Comment: @prisoner_of_azkaban, Could you please post the full answer if you got it resolved?